# Parsing Wordpress XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Im migrating big Wordpress page to custom CMS. I need to extract information from big (20MB+) XML file, exported from Wordpress.

1. I don't have any experience in XML under PHP and i don't know how to start reading file.
2. Wordpress file contains structures like this:

   ```
   <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[Encoded text here]]></excerpt:encoded>
   ```

and i don't know how to handle this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your XML example didn't come through.

PHP5 ships with two extensions for working with XML - [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) and "[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php)".
Generally speaking, I recommend looking into SimpleXML first since it's the more accessible library of the two.

For starters, use "[simplexml_load_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)" to read an XML file into an object for further processing.
You should also check out the "[SimpleXML basic examples page on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)".

Answer (score 4):

You are probably going to do fine with simplexml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('big_xml_file.xml');
foreach ($xml->element as $el) {
    echo $el->name;
}
```

See [php.net](http://php.net/simplexml) for more info

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any experience in XML under PHP

Take a look at [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) or [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

> `<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[Encoded text here]]></excerpt:encoded>`

This should not be a problem for the XML parser. However, you will have a problem with the content exported by WordPress. For example, it can contain [WordPress shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), which will come across in their raw format instead of expanded.

#### Better Approach

Determine if what you are migrating to supports an export from WordPress feature. Many other systems do - Drupal, Joomla, Octopress, etc.

Comment: Target is custom CMS wrote by someone else. If there are shortcodes - i w will probably handle them manually in PHP (somehow).

Answer (score 1):

Although Adam is Absolutely right, his answer needed a bit more details. Here's a simple script that should get you going.

```
$xmlfile  = simplexml_load_file('yourxmlfile.xml');
foreach ($xmlfile->channel->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item->xpath('title'));
    var_dump($item->xpath('wp:post_type'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simplexml_load_file() is the way to go creating an object, but you will also need to use xpath as WordPress uses name spaces. If I remember correctly SimpleXML does not handle name space well or at all.

`$xml = simplexml_load_file( $file );
$xml->xpath('/rss/channel/wp:category');`

I would recommend looking at what WordPress uses for importing the files.

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php